# Adding text with apparent incorrect inclination

Tags: plotting

**[Edited]** I'm trying to add some text adjacent to a curve with the condition of having the same inclination as its tangent line. As a toy example, consider the following situation:

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 3 Pi}]
x=8.3;
y=Sin[x];
m=D[Sin[t],t]/.t->x;
```

Now, even if I use the tangent's slope to rotate the text, the inclination is wrong:

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 3 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Rotate[Text["Some inclined text"], ArcTan[m]], {x, y}]]
```

[image]

As [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414712/how-do-i-get-text-to-rotate-correctly) suggested, it seems related to the `AspectRatio` since there is no problem in the following cases:

```
Plot[m*(t-x)+y, {t, 0, 3 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Rotate[Text["---------"], ArcTan[m]], {x, y}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Sin[t], m (t - x) + y}, {t, 0, 3 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Rotate[Text["---------"], ArcTan[m]], {x, y}]]
```

[image]

Any idea how to address this? Thanks

Comment: If you insist on using text for this, the easiest fix is to set `ApectRatio->Automatic`. Alternatively, you can divide `m` by the aspect ratio of the plot, so `m=D[...]*GoldenRatio` for the default aspect ratio

Comment: I don't want to use text to draw the tangent line; I have modified the question to -hopefully- make it more transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take into account both the `AspectRatio` and the actual `PlotRange`, both of which you can extract with `AbsoluteOptions` after plotting.

Exemplary code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f = Sin;
x = 3;
y = f[x];
m = D[f[t], t] /. t -> x;

p = Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 3 Pi}, 
   Epilog -> {Inset[
      Rotate[Style[Text["-----Some inclined text-----"], 
        FontSize -> 15], ArcTan[ϕ]], {x, y}]}];

{{xran, yran}, arat} = {PlotRange, AspectRatio} /. AbsoluteOptions[p];

p /. ϕ -> m * arat * (xran[[2]] - xran[[1]]) / (yran[[2]] - yran[[1]])
```

[image: Inclined text]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was missing. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the Inset a direction instead of rotating the text (I added a red point):

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 3 Pi}]
x = 8.3;
y = Sin[x];
m := Sin'[x];
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 3 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[Text["            Some inclined text"], {x, y}, 
    Automatic, 10, {1, -1}], Red, Point[{x, y}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

y[x_] = Sin[x];
```

The tangent line at `x == x0` is

```
y2[x_, x0_] = y'[x0]*(x - x0) + y[x0];

Manipulate[
 Legended[
  Show[
   Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 3 Pi}],
   Plot[y2[x, x0], {x, x0 - 0.5, x0 + 0.5}]],
  Placed[
   LineLegend[
    ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {y[x], "tangent"}],
   {.5, .7}]],
 {{x0, 8.3, Subscript[x, 0]}, 0, 3 Pi, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use text to draw the tangent line; I have modified the question to -hopefully- make it more transparent.